# Debugging Laravel with Xdebug in IntelliJ IDEA/PhpStorm with artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am trying to figure out how to properly debug a Laravel controller using the `artisan serve` command. It seems in Laravel 8+ the serve command calls `pcntl_proc` and creates a sub-process, the breakpoints that are inside the sub-process are not captured by both IDEA and PhpStorm.

Can someone suggest a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the following to my xdebug.ini file

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.output_dir=/tmp
```

pcntl process picks up these values and process debuging normally